# Java - why is the mouseClicked method not permanently resetting variables when it's done being executed?

Tags: java

I have a 2D array of cell objects which contain a String variable for its "tileCode", when I set the active tile code with the keyboard and then click on the desired cell in the 2D array, it should change that cells tileCode to the current active tile. But after I click on the tile, it immediately switches back to its previous tile code and image.

By default, each tile is set to a floor.

```
public static JFrame frame = new JFrame("Tool");
public static Panel panel;

public Image wall, floor;

public int rows = 50;
public int cols = 50;
public int xCoor = 20;
public int yCoor = 20;

String activeKey = "f";
Image activeImage = floor;

//Arrays
Rectangle[][] recs = new Rectangle[rows][cols];
Cell[][] cells = new Cell[rows][cols];
public Set <Integer> keysDown = new HashSet<>();

public LevelDesignTool() {
    loadImages();
    panel = new Panel();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(1400, 1100);
    frame.setFocusable(true);
    frame.requestFocus();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.getContentPane().add(panel);

    KeyboardFocusManager manager = KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager();
    manager.addKeyEventDispatcher(this);
    addMouseListener(this);

    myThread thread = new myThread();
    thread.start();
}

class Panel extends JPanel {

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        Graphics2D g2D = (Graphics2D)g;

        //Loading array of Tile Types
        ArrayList<String> TileTypes = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            Scanner TileFileScanner = new Scanner(new File("TileTypes"));

            while(TileFileScanner.hasNext()) {
                TileTypes.add(TileFileScanner.nextLine());
            }

        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.err.println("Tile Type file not found.");
        }


        g.setFont(new Font("Italic",Font.PLAIN, 25));
        g.drawString("Press Enter to save to file.", 1050, 50);

        //Tile Type key on the rigt side of the screen
        int y = 550;
        for(int i = 0; i < TileTypes.size(); i++) {
            g.drawString(TileTypes.get(i), 1050, y);
            y += 30;
        }

        //Creating 2D array of Rectangles
        xCoor = 20;
        for(int r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
            yCoor = 20;
            for(int c = 0; c < cols; c++) {
                recs[r][c] = new Rectangle(xCoor, yCoor, 18, 18);
                yCoor += 19;
            }
            xCoor += 19;
        }
        //Creating 2D array of cells
        for(int r = 0; r < rows; r++) {

            for(int c = 0; c < cols; c++) {

                cells[r][c] = new Cell(recs[r][c], "f", activeImage);
                xCoor += 21;
            }
            xCoor = 0;
            yCoor += 21;
        }
        //Drawing cells
        for(int r = 0; r < rows; r++) {

            for(int c = 0; c < cols; c++) {

                g.fillRect((int)cells[r][c].r.getX(), (int)cells[r][c].r.getY(), (int)cells[r][c].r.getWidth(), (int)cells[r][c].r.getHeight());
                g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            }
        }
        //Drawing the images stored in each cell object
        for(int r = 0; r < rows; r++) {

            for(int c = 0; c < cols; c++) {

                cells[r][c].image = floor;
                g.drawImage(cells[r][c].getImage(), cells[r][c].getX(), cells[r][c].getY(), this);
            }
        }


        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() { 

            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

                for(int r = 0; r < rows; r++) {

                    for(int c = 0; c < cols; c++) {

                        if (cells[r][c].getRect().contains(e.getX(), e.getY())) {
                            cells[r][c].tileCode = activeKey;
                            cells[r][c].image = activeImage;
                            //System.out.println("click registered");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }); 
    }
}

//Must have these implemeted because they are from an interface
@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {}
@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}
@Override
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}
@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {}
@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {}


public void update() throws Exception {

    //System.out.println(cells[0][0].getTileCode());
    //System.out.println(activeKey);
}

@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {

    if(event.getID() == KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED){
        keysDown.add(event.getKeyCode());
        if(event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_F) {
            activeKey = "f";
            activeImage = floor;
        }
        if(event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_E) {
            activeKey = "e";
        }
        if(event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_W) {
            activeKey = "w";
            activeImage = wall;
        }
    }
    if(event.getID() == KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED) 
        keysDown.remove(event.getKeyCode());

    return false;
}

class myThread extends Thread {
    public void run() {
        while(true) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(15);
                frame.repaint();
                update();   //update any game state changes for the next frame
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        }
    }
}

private void loadImages() {
    floor = new ImageIcon("images/Floor.png").getImage();
    wall = new ImageIcon("images/Wall.png").getImage();
}

//Runs code
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new LevelDesignTool();
}
```

}

once I click on a cell, its image should change to the active image and the tile code should change to the active tile code.

Comment: In the future please provide a complete (compilable, runnable) example that demonstrates the problem, with any irrelevant removed. Running the code makes it much easier to see what is wrong. At first I thought this might be related to having multiple mouseListeners, or maybe a repainting problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

problem is that you are initializing your data (and adding a new mouseListener) on every call to paintComponent. That resets all the data to "floor" every time it repaints, which overrides any change you made in the mouse listener. Also, notice that in your "Drawing cells" loop, you reset the image to floor (`cells[r][c].image = floor;`) just before you draw it. This again resets the data you set in your mouse listener.

The solution is to move your mouseListener and your initialization code into a constructor for Panel, like this:

```
class Panel extends JPanel {
    ArrayList<String> TileTypes = new ArrayList<String>();
    public Panel() {
        //Loading array of Tile Types
        try {
            Scanner TileFileScanner = new Scanner(new File("TileTypes"));
            while(TileFileScanner.hasNext()) {
                TileTypes.add(TileFileScanner.nextLine());
            }
        } catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.err.println("Tile Type file not found.");
        }

        //Creating 2D array of Rectangles
        xCoor = 20;
        for(int r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
            yCoor = 20;
            for(int c = 0; c < cols; c++) {
                recs[r][c] = new Rectangle(xCoor, yCoor, 18, 18);
                yCoor += 19;
            }
            xCoor += 19;
        }

        //Creating 2D array of cells
        for(int r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
            for(int c = 0; c < cols; c++) {
                cells[r][c] = new Cell(recs[r][c], "f", activeImage);
                cells[r][c].image = floor;
                xCoor += 21;
            }
            xCoor = 0;
            yCoor += 21;
        }

        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() { 
            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                for(int r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
                    for(int c = 0; c < cols; c++) {
                        if (cells[r][c].getRect().contains(e.getX(), e.getY())) {
                            cells[r][c].tileCode = activeKey;
                            cells[r][c].image = activeImage;
                            //System.out.println("click registered");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }); 
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2D = (Graphics2D)g;
        g.setFont(new Font("Italic",Font.PLAIN, 25));
        g.drawString("Press Enter to save to file.", 1050, 50);

        //Tile Type key on the rigt side of the screen
        int y = 550;
        for(int i = 0; i < TileTypes.size(); i++) {
            g.drawString(TileTypes.get(i), 1050, y);
            y += 30;
        }

        //Drawing cells
        for(int r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
            for(int c = 0; c < cols; c++) {
                g.fillRect((int)cells[r][c].r.getX(), (int)cells[r][c].r.getY(),
                           (int)cells[r][c].r.getWidth(), (int)cells[r][c].r.getHeight());
                g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            }
        }
        //Drawing the images stored in each cell object
        for(int r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
            for(int c = 0; c < cols; c++) {
                g.drawImage(cells[r][c].getImage(), cells[r][c].getX(), cells[r][c].getY(), this);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also, not part of your question, but you are discarding the interrupted exception in your thread. Do this instead:

```
public void run() {
    while (!Thread.interrupted()) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(15);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this fixed the problem I was having, it works now.